# Error messages using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

**JQuery Version** `v1.11.0`

At the beginning of my script I have the following function:

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {
    alert('Error : '+msg+'\nprogram: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+linenumber);
    return true;
}
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Error : Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'enable'
program: http://localhost:8050/robocon/scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js
Line Number: 924
```

**The problem is not the error itself**. The problem is the program/line reported. It takes me to nowhere, and I noticed that other errors take me to the same program & nonsense number line. How can I get the correct program/line number?

Answer (score 0):

First you are not using jquery on this code. That beeing said, here´s an example using only javascript, that is avaiable [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror), adapted:

```
var gOldOnError = window.onerror;
// Override previous handler.
window.onerror = function myErrorHandler(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
  if (gOldOnError)
    // Call previous handler.
    alert('Error : '+errorMsg+'\nprogram: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+lineNumber);

  // Just let default handler run.
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I didnt include the jquery code because the problem is not there. With your suggested code I got the same answer.  Ill prepare a resumed code for tgest purposes.